# 6 x 6 matrix for calculating Jordan Canonical form

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could you please tell me some examples of 6 by 6 matrix ?!?

The matrix must have 6 strictly complex conjuage eigenvalues(3 pairs), for example Lamdas = +2j, -2j, 3j, -3j, 4j, -4j.

Comment: For a smart-aleck response... consider a diagonal matrix with those as the entries along the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0&2&0&0&0&0 \\
-2&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&3&0&0 \\
0&0&-3&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-4&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$